# How to replace double spaces by one space, tabulations by one space and delete \n and \r with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, spaces

I'm french so sorry for the orthograph...
I never did some XSL
I have an XML that i know not in input and i try to replace double space by on space, tabulations by one space and delete \n and \r with XSL

I saw on Internet normalize-space() or translate but i'm not sure that's the solution...

Could you help me?

Thanks

An exemple of the XML file could be :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <input>
       something   with       
 a   lot   of    space and new lines
  </input>
  <input2>
      <subInput2>
       something   with       
 a   lot   of    space and new lines
      </subInput2>
  </input2>
```

Comment: The example is a poor one, since it's not XML (multiple root elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize spaces in all text nodes of the entire XML document, do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this does not affect text in attributes. If you want these to be processed too, do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normalize-space() is the way to go.. its valid in all versions of xslt.  see http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp for details.

I really ought to add that in xml the extra whitespace is ignored in the same fashion as it does in html unless you have explicitly set options to <xsl:preserve-space>. So I would say that - as a rule of thumb - you don't always need use normalize-space() everywhere you see extra space.

example:

input:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <input>

       something   with       
 a   lot   of    space and new lines

  </input>
```

realy simple xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

result:

```
 <result>something with a lot of space</result>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, after reading the link given it seems me normalize-space() can't delete \n and \r in the file, is it right ?

Comment: I've added a really simple example.   If your scenario is different to this, please post an example in the question.